# Is Sidney being sarcastic in this line?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

At a basement club scene from *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Hunsbecker rival columnist
Leo Bartha insults Hunsbecker's press agent Sidney, who then meet Mr Elwell:

> Sidney: "Leo," I says, "J.J. froze me out, so I'm eating humble pie
> this month. Please, please print me an item."
>
> Mr Elwell: And instead he printed his heel in your face, hmm?
>
> Sidney: **You're full of human feelings**.
>
> Mr Elwell: Turn the record over, Sidney.

Is Sidney being sarcastic in this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's pure and direct irony. He means that Elwell failed to show empathy in his response.

Lots of good idiomatic and witty lines in that screenplay! Freeze out, eat humble pie, sound like a broken record...